# How to auto-set chromedriver path?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have a program that I give out to my friends that utilizes selenium chromedriver. For alot of them its very annooying/complicated having to input the chromedriver path everytime they want to use the program. Is there anyway to automatically detect and set the chromedriver path for them?

This is the line of code that I have to use to set the chromedriver path

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/users/blake/Desktop/chromedriver.exe");
```

I want to know how to make the "C:/users/blake/Desktop/chromedriver.exe" be automatically detected rather than manually inputted.

Thanks!

Comment: Read the PATH and expect the entry there or provide it by yourself in your package. Thats what i would do in this case, and lots of application work.

Comment: also there is option to install webdriver in you code if you are sure yout friends does not have webdriver isntalled:  WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup(); But I don't know what happens if you run the code twice.

Answer (score 4):

To set and define Chrome driver, You can include chromedriver.exe file in your project folder and you can set driver path respective to project folder.

Syntax:

```
filepath=  "./folderName/chromedriver.exe";
```

OR

```
filepath= ".\\chromedriver.exe";
```

Here Dot(.) includes project path, the Work set in which you are working.  by using this logic, Every time we don't need to define and update driver path.

Answer (score 2):

You could put the driver in the home folder and ask Java to serch in the home folder.

`System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "chromedriver.exe").getAbsolutePath());`

It will be OS independent.

Answer (score 0):

You can create folder inside your project and put chromedriver.exe there Every time when you share your project to other then they don't need to download chromedriver.

Below line of code you can include in your code:-

```
String path = System.getProperty("user.dir");   // return project folder path

String driverpath = path + "\\driverfolder\\chromedriver.exe";   // return driver folder path 

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",driverpath );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os 
from os.path import expanduser

User = expanduser("~")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=(User)+'/Desktop/chromedriver')
```

this will pull the users user directory and all you have to do is tell them to move the chromedriver into there Desktop

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two ways.

1) Set the path for chromedriver to the `resources` folder. It's usually created automatically when creating Maven project. Or, it could be any other folder within project structure.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src\\main\\resources\\chromedriver.exe"); // "[folder]\\chromedriver.exe"
```

2) If you will not specify `"webdriver.chrome.driver"` property Selenium will be looking for driver in your `C:\Windows` folder.