# Python code on mac not functioning properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I downloaded a change.org auto filler and all its prerequisites, but every time I run the module it outputs this error:

```
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 72, in start
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1702, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'chromedriver'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/---/Desktop/Bot/ChangeOrgSignBot-master/bot.py", line 21, in <module>
    defualt_driver = wd.Chrome()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 81, in start
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

I'm on Mac OS X Catalina 10.15.5 using Python 3.8.3

I have tried moving the chromedriver into /usr/local/bin and also just putting it in the local directory with the program but nothing works

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Output of `echo $PATH` would be helpful as it will say which are the expected paths.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to auto-set chromedriver path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50143872/how-to-auto-set-chromedriver-path)

Answer (score 0):

You can also download chromedriver from [chromium.org](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads). Then place it in the same project folder and use like:

```
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')
```